# How to delete authenticated user from firebase in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

when clicking on a button i called a function,

```
onDelete(id:string){ this.db.collection('Students').doc(id).delete(); }
```

Here, id is a name of document that i want to delete, db is a property of type AngularFireStore, 'Students' is a name of collection.

Structure of document:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CexI.png)
 In the above image, collection name is Students, under which multiple documents exist, since document name must be unique so i given that name a number of type string which acts as id. In every document, there is email field, i want to delete that email from authentication when i delete the same document.

code to sign up users:

```
this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email:string,password:string).then(res=>{})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a user existing in Firebase authentication you have two possibilities:

### 1/ Using the JavaScript SDK (since your app is made with angular)

You call the [`delete()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#delete) method, as follows:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
user.delete()
.then(() => {
   //....
})
.catch(err => {
  if (err.code === "auth/requires-recent-login") {
     //Re-authenticate the user 
  } else {
     //....
  }
})
```

Note however, that this method "requires the user to have recently signed in. If this requirement isn't met, ask the user to authenticate again and then call `firebase.User.reauthenticateWithCredential`". An error with the `auth/requires-recent-login` code is "thrown if the user's last sign-in time does not meet the security threshold".

**So, only the logged-in user can call this method from a front-end, in order to delete his/her own account.**

### 2/ Using the Admin SDK

You can use the Admin SDK's [`deleteUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#delete) method, for example within a Cloud Function.

In this case, there is no need to have the user logged-in since this is executed in the back-end and it is therefore possible to delete any user.

For example, you could have a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) triggered **by an admin user**.

Another possibility, is to trigger a Cloud Function upon the Firestore user's document deletion.

---

## Update based on your Question update:

I understand that you want to delete the user record in the Auth service upon deletion. For that you can write a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) as follows:

```
exports.deleteUser = functions.firestore
    .document('Students/{studentID}')
    .onDelete((snap, context) => {

        const deletedValue = snap.data();
        const userEmail = deletedValue.Email;

        return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(userEmail)
            .then(userRecord => {
                const userID = userRecord.uid;
                return admin.auth().deleteUser(userID)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.message);
                return null;
            })

    });
```

Comment: Thanks Renaud for answering. My question is, admin want to delete selected students from the database,in my case firestore,then by getting document name , data can be deleted but the email id would be still present in the authentication. So i want to delete selected authentication by logging admin. Means, admin want to delete other authenticated users. Hope you got my point.

Comment: Yes I get your point: the solution is to go with the the second option, i.e. the admin triggers a Cloud Function which calls the Admin SDK's `deleteUser()` method.

Comment: @ArunMishra That all sounds like information that you should add to your question (there's an `edit` link right under it). The whole Firestore angle is completely missing there, which makes it hard to help.

Comment: How do you delete the user document in Firestore? And what is the id and structure of the user documents? Please add this information to your question, by using the edit link.

Comment: Hey Renaud, i have edited the question. Hope this time i m clear in explaining my doubt.